# Does incrementing in a member initializer list generate undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, ctor-initializer

Is this causing undefined behaviour? Specifically, the incrementing in the initializer list and how will that be evaluated.

```
class Wrinkle {
public:
    Wrinkle(int i) : a(++i), b(++i), x(++i) {}
private:
    int a;
    int x;
    int b;
};
```

The difference in order between the declaration of members and initializer list is intended since this is an example that would showcase exactly that difference, so please ignore it for now.

Comment: What are your expected values for `a`, `b` and `x` if you are doing `Wrinkle tmp{1}`?

Comment: `Wrinkle(int i) : a(i+1), b(i+2), x(i+3) {}`

Comment: @BoPersson That looks like the wrong order. I'd expect `a, x, b`.

Comment: note that the members are initialized in the order they appear in the declaration not in the order they appear in the initializer list. Your compiler should show you a warning for this code. And imho thats a complete showstopper for what you want to do there: The initial values will change (unexpectetly) if you rearrange the declaration of the members. Thats a good way to confuse anybody refactoring your code (including yourself) for zero benefit

Comment: ...nevertheless its is a interesting question from the language-lawyer point of view

Comment: @melpomene - yes, that's the order the values would be initialized, but I suspect the OP wants the three values in the order of the initializer-list. Anyway, if you are explicit you get the values you want, and don't have to ask here. :-)

Comment: Not sure if there is explicit wording, but uses like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10720377/3002139) strongly imply this is intended to be legal at least.

Comment: Wow. I just realised that I **rely** on this being well-defined. I hadn't even ever wondered. *[upvotes and crosses fingers]* Note that this answer says there is a sequence point between the initialisation of each member: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2669894/2757035

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializer list \*argument\* evaluation order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589950/initializer-list-argument-evaluation-order)

Comment: @BaummitAugen - I'm not sure the linked question does imply that, because sequence of member initialization is described separately from sequencing of other side effect. It may still _also_ be true, of course.

Comment: @underscore_d also not quite, because the standard describes sequencing of value computation and side-effects separately too.

Comment: @Useless It's not proof of course, but looks like a rather strong hint to me.

Comment: This is not production code, I took it from an example from CppCon. It was designed to showcase the initializer list vs order of declaration initialization order. I took the example and discussed it with someone and the undefined behaviour idea came into discussion.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This does not generate *Undefined Behavior* because:

[[class.base.init]#7](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#7)

> [ *Note:* The initialization performed by each mem-initializer constitutes a full-expression. Any expression in a mem-initializer is evaluated as part of the full-expression that performs the initialization. ]

[[intro.execution]](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution)

> [5.](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#5) A full-expression is
>
> - [...]
> - an init-declarator or a mem-initializer, including the constituent expressions of the initializer,
>
> [9.](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#9) Every value computation and side effect associated with a full-expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated.

---

But beware that:

[[class.base.init]#13](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#13)

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>
> - [...]
> - Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).

So your code will effectively assign `i + 1` to `a`, `i + 2` to `x` and `i + 3` to `b`.

Comment: Note that this rule is also what makes access to other members work, as in `Wrinkle() : a(rand()), b(a + 1) {}`

Answer (score 6):

The C++17 standard contains an example [almost exactly the same as in the question](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init#7):

```
struct B1 { B1(int); /* ... */ };
struct B2 { B2(int); /* ... */ };
struct D : B1, B2 {
  D(int);
  B1 b;
  const int c;
};

D::D(int a) : B2(a+1), B1(a+2), c(a+3), b(a+4) { /* ... */ }
D d(10);
```

This is followed by a note:

> [ Note: The initialization performed by each mem-initializer constitutes a full-expression (4.6). Any expression in a mem-initializer is evaluated as part of the full-expression that performs the initialization. — end note ]

Following the link, section 4.6 tells us that one of the [definitions of "full-expression" is](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#5.3)

> ... a mem-initializer, including the constituent expressions of the initializer,

The phrase "including constituent expressions of the initiailizer" strongly suggests to me that the above code is legal, because the side effects of `++i` will have completed before moving on to the next initializer. This is just my reading of the standard though, I'm happy to defer to anyone with more standardese experience than me.

(It's also worth noting that initialization of members will happen in the order in which they are declared in the class, not in the order in which they appear in the member initializer list).

Comment: *"almost exactly the same as in the question"* - Except that there are no pre-increment on `a` in this example, which is the main point of the question.

Comment: @Holt now edited, but I see that you've come to the same conclusion in the mean time :)